# How can I test a rails 4 confirm dialog with Capybara and Poltergeist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to test that a link to a destroy action throws a native browser `confirm` box with the correct message.

The link is being generated using rails' `link_to`:

```
link_to 'Delete', user_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

And generates the following html:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/users/6" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

The functionality is working correctly in the browser, but I want to test for it in my `rspec` feature spec.

I'm trying to stub out the browser's `confirm` function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485884/how-does-one-test-the-content-of-confirm-dialogs-using-poltergeist) and in [this gist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/50#issuecomment-33277170), however I can't get it to work.

```
it 'requests confirmation', js: true do
  visit user_path(user)
  page.execute_script "
    window.confirmMsg = null;
    window.confirm = function(msg) { window.confirmMsg = msg; return true; };"
  click_link 'Delete'
  expect(page.evaluate_script('window.confirmMsg')).to eq('Are you sure?')
end
```

Gives the following error from `rspec`:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page.evaluate_script('window.confirmMsg')).to eq('Are you sure?')

       expected: "Are you sure?"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
```

However, if I call a `confirm` directly via `page.execute_script`:

```
it 'requests confirmation', js: true do
  visit user_path(user)
  page.execute_script "
    window.confirmMsg = null;
    window.confirm = function(msg) { window.confirmMsg = msg; return true; };
    window.confirm('Are you sure?');"
  expect(page.evaluate_script('window.confirmMsg')).to eq('Are you sure?')
end
```

Then the test passes.

Also clicking the Delete link will cause the test to fail, even if `confirm` has been called directly for `page.execute_script`:

```
it 'requests confirmation', js: true do
  visit user_path(user)
  page.execute_script "
    window.confirmMsg = null;
    window.confirm = function(msg) { window.confirmMsg = msg; return true; };
    window.confirm('Are you sure?');"
  click_link 'Delete'
  expect(page.evaluate_script('window.confirmMsg')).to eq('Are you sure?')
end
```

Gives the same error from `rspec`:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page.evaluate_script('window.confirmMsg')).to eq('Are you sure?')

       expected: "Are you sure?"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
```

**Why is the test failing? And, how can I test confirm dialogues correctly?**

---

**Context:**

I'm running my tests from a Vagrant virtual machine, which is `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS` and running `ruby 2.1.2p95`.

My `Gemfile.lock` shows that I have the following versions:

```
rails (4.1.4)
poltergeist (1.5.1)
capybara (2.4.1)
```

Answer (score 33):

page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms is deprecated. Instead use

```
page.accept_confirm do
  click_link 'Delete'
end
```

Comment: Documentation: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#modals, which includes examples for `accept_alert`, `dismiss_confirm`, `accept_prompt`.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, you [cannot do this](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/80), because Poltergeist does work only in one window.

For that specific test you will need to use Selenium and this API:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

If you are concerned about wanting to run your tests headless, you can use Xvfb (X Virtual Framebuffer) like this:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24+32
```

Alternatively you can also use capybara-webkit:

```
page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms
page.driver.browser.reject_js_confirms
```

However, I have made the best experience using a mixture of (mostly) Poltergeist and Selenium where necessary.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I'm not trying to accept the confirm, I'm trying to assert that it's thrown. This issue thread suggests that it should be possible: https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/50#issuecomment-33277170 - but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can you explain the significance of Poltegeist working in only one window? Why does the test I outlined work when I call `window.confirm()` directly from `page.execute_script`, but not when I `click_link('Delete')`.

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the above, when using Selenium you can test the actual text of the confirm dialog using the following:

```
    click_link 'Delete'
    a = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
    expect(a.text).to eq("Are you sure?")
    a.accept
```

Also, just found a good test for whether the alert is present here: [selenium 2.4.0, how to check for presence of an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076758/selenium-2-4-0-how-to-check-for-presence-of-an-alert) I slightly modified it, put in my spec_helper file as:

```
def alert_present?
  begin
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
    return true
  rescue
    return false
  end
end
```

And then in your test just do:

```
click_link 'Delete'
expect(alert_present?).to eq(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this Javascript:

```
confirm('You have unsaved changes, do you want to continue?')
```

For Poltergiest I found the following to work:

```
expect(page.driver.browser.modal_message).eq 'You have unsaved changes, do you want to contine?'

page.driver.browser.dismiss_confirm
page.driver.browser.accept_confirm
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am doing in Rails 3.2 and `capybara (~> 2.18.0)`

```
context 'when `All listing` overlaps with listing 1' do
  it 'displays warning' do
    set_weekday_times('.show_window','10:00 AM', '02:00 PM', listing1.address)
    set_weekday_times('.show_window:last-child', '11:00 AM', '03:00 PM', 'All Listing')

    # button click event that triggers the confirm to appear
    submit_weekdays_form

    # Get the message in the confirm dialog
    confirm_text = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text
    expect(confirm_text).to include('overlapping show windows on Sunday')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to test JavaScript behavior. But if you want to check confirmation message, it might be okay to test link attribute only without Poltergeist:

```
it 'requests confirmation' do
  visit user_path(user)
  delete_link = find_link 'Delete', href: user_path(user)
  expect(delete_link['data-confirm']).to eq 'Are you sure?'
end
```

Here is the alternative:

```
it 'requests confirmation' do
  visit user_path(user)
  expect(page).to have_selector "a[data-confirm='Are you sure?'][href='#{user_path(user)}']", text: 'Delete'
end
```

This test cannot check if JS is working correctly, but it might be enough for the most of cases. (And fast!)